# How do I get the maximum memory usage of a docker container?

Tags: docker, memory, statistics, containers

I have a docker image and would like to know how much memory it consumes when running. [Docker stats](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) can give you a stream of that data, but it does not give you a statistic (like the max. memory used) overall runtime. Is there a tool that can do that?

I would like to do something smarter than: `docker stats my_container --format "table {{.MemUsage}}" >> tmp.txt` and then searching in `tmp.txt` for the max memory.

I mean that works, but it's not great...

Comment: +1 Something smarter would be great, given the `docker stats` command only captures every second, so may give an incorrect peak usage.